# Convolutional LSTM Model Dimension Incompatibility when making predictions & prediction dimension issues

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, lstm, tensorflow2.0, sequential

I structured a Convolutional LSTM model to predict the forthcoming Bitcoin price data, using the analyzed past data of the Bitcoin close price and other features.

Let me jump straight to the code:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import keras_tuner as kt
from keras_tuner import HyperParameters as hp
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import InputLayer, ConvLSTM1D, LSTM, Flatten, RepeatVector, Dense, TimeDistributed
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

from tensorflow.keras.metrics import RootMeanSquaredError
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras.backend as K
from keras.losses import Huber

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
```

```
DIR = '../input/btc-features-targets'
SEG_DIR = '../input/segmented'

segmentized_features = os.listdir(SEG_DIR)
btc_train_features = []
for seg in segmentized_features:
  train_features = pd.read_csv(f'{SEG_DIR}/{seg}')
  train_features.set_index('date', inplace=True)
  btc_train_features.append(scaler.fit_transform(train_features.values))

btc_train_targets = pd.read_csv(f'{DIR}/btc_train_targets.csv')
btc_train_targets.set_index('date', inplace=True)

btc_test_features = pd.read_csv(f'{DIR}/btc_test_features.csv')
btc_tef1 = btc_test_features.iloc[:111]
btc_tef2 = btc_test_features.iloc[25:]
btc_tef1.set_index('date', inplace=True)
btc_tef2.set_index('date', inplace=True)

btc_test_targets = pd.read_csv(f'{DIR}/btc_test_targets.csv')
btc_test_targets.set_index('date', inplace=True)

btc_trt_log = np.log(btc_train_targets)

btc_tefs1 = scaler.fit_transform(btc_tef1.values)
btc_tefs2 = scaler.fit_transform(btc_tef2.values)
btc_tet_log = np.log(btc_test_targets)
```

```
scaled_train_features = []

for features in btc_train_features:
  shape = features.shape
  scaled_train_features.append(np.expand_dims(features, [0,3]))

shape_2 = btc_tefs1.shape
btc_tefs1 = np.expand_dims(btc_tefs1, [0,3])

shape_3 = btc_tefs2.shape
btc_tefs2 = np.expand_dims(btc_tefs2, [0,3])

btc_trt_log = btc_trt_log.values[0]
btc_tet_log = btc_tet_log.values[0]
```

```
def build(hp):
  model = keras.Sequential()

  # Input Layer
  model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(111,32,1)))

  # ConvLSTM1D
  convLSTM_hp_filters = hp.Int(name='convLSTM_filters', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  convLSTM_hp_kernel_size = hp.Choice(name='convLSTM_kernel_size', values=[3,5,7])
  convLSTM_activation = hp.Choice(name='convLSTM_activation', values=['selu', 'relu'])
  model.add(ConvLSTM1D(filters=convLSTM_hp_filters,
                    kernel_size=convLSTM_hp_kernel_size,
                    padding='same',
                    activation=convLSTM_activation,
                    use_bias=True,
                    bias_initializer='zeros'))

  # Flatten
  model.add(Flatten())

  # RepeatVector
  model.add(RepeatVector(5))

  # LSTM
  LSTM_hp_units = hp.Int(name='LSTM_units', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  LSTM_activation = hp.Choice(name='LSTM_activation', values=['selu', 'relu'])
  model.add(LSTM(units=LSTM_hp_units, activation=LSTM_activation, return_sequences=True))

  # TimeDistributed Dense
  dense_units = hp.Int(name='dense_units', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
  dense_activation = hp.Choice(name='dense_activation', values=['selu', 'relu'])
  model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=dense_units, activation=dense_activation)))

  # TimeDistributed Dense_Output
  model.add(Dense(1))

  # Set Learning Rate
  hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice(name='learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])

  # Compile Model
  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
              loss=Huber(),
              metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])

  return model
```

```
tuner = kt.Hyperband(build,
                     objective=kt.Objective('root_mean_squared_error', direction='min'),
                     max_epochs=10,
                     factor=3)
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='root_mean_squared_error', patience=5)

opt_hps = []
for train_features in scaled_train_features:

  tuner.search(train_features, btc_trt_log, epochs=50, callbacks=[early_stop])
  opt_hps.append(tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0])

models, epochs = ([] for _ in range(2))

for hps in opt_hps: 

  model = tuner.hypermodel.build(hps)
  models.append(model)

  history = model.fit(train_features, btc_trt_log, epochs=70, verbose=0)

  rmse = history.history['root_mean_squared_error']
  best_epoch = rmse.index(min(rmse)) + 1
  epochs.append(best_epoch)
```

```
hypermodel = tuner.hypermodel.build(opt_hps[0])
for train_features, epoch in zip(scaled_train_features, epochs): hypermodel.fit(train_features, btc_trt_log, epochs=epoch)
```

```
tp1 = hypermodel.predict(btc_tefs1).flatten()
tp2 = hypermodel.predict(btc_tefs2).flatten()

test_predictions = np.concatenate((tp1, tp2[86:]), axis=None)
```

The hyperparameters of the model are configured using `keras_tuner`; as there were `ResourceExhaustError` issues output by the notebook when training is done with the full features dataset, sequentially segmented datasets are used instead (and apparently, referring to the study done utilizing the similar model architecture, training is able to be efficiently done through this training approach).

The input dimension of each segmented dataset is `(111,32,1)`.

There aren't any issues reported until before the last code block. The models work fine. Yet, when the `.predict()` function is executed, the notebook prints out an error, which states that the dimension of the input features for making predictions is incompatible with the dimension of the input features used while training. I did not understand the reason behind its occurrence, since as far as I know, the input dimensions of a train dataset for a DNN model cannot be identical as the input dimensions of a test dataset.

Even though all the price data from 2018 to early 2021 are used as training datasets, predictions are only needed for the mid 2021 timeframe.

The dataset used for prediction has a dimension of `(136,32,1)`.

I tried matching the dimension of this dataset to `(111,32,1)`, through index slicing.

Now this showed issues in the output dimension. While predictions should be made for 136 data points, the result only returned 10.

Are there any issues relevant to the model configuration? Cannot interpret the current situation.